# Highlight DataGrid Row if Cell Equals X

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I am using an asp:DataGrid bound to a DataSet which is filled by my SQLDataAdapter. Before the asp:DataGrid is displayed on my page, I want to check the asp:DataGrid, and for each amount equal to $10.00, I want to highlight the row yellow.

**Here is my VB CodeBehind**

```
    'Create a connection
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection("Yes, this works")
    'Create the command object, passing in the SQL string
    Const strSQL As String = "SELECT CUID, Account, Amount / 100 as Amount, Serial FROM [ACCU].[dbo].[ERN_ITEM_VIEW] Where Date = '04/13/2017' And CUID <> '0'"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)
    'Create the DataAdapter
    Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter()
    myDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
    'Populate the DataSet
    Dim myDS As New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDS)
    'Set the datagrid's datasource to the dataset and databind
    ERNDataGrid.DataSource = myDS
    ERNDataGrid.DataBind()
    'Display Information on what page we are currently viewing
    lblMessage.Text = "Viewing Page " & ERNDataGrid.CurrentPageIndex + 1 & " of " & ERNDataGrid.PageCount
```

**Here is my asp:DataGrid**

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="ERNDataGrid" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px"
        CellPadding="2" Width="100%"
        Font-Name="Verdana"
        Font-Size="Smaller"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#77a13d"
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#dddddd"
        AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="15"
        OnPageIndexChanged="ERNDataGrid_PageIndexChanged" Font-Names="Verdana">

        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#464646" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrev" HorizontalAlign="Right"
            ForeColor="White" BackColor="#464646"
            NextPageText="Next Page >>" PrevPageText="<< Prev. Page" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False"></PagerStyle>

        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#DDDDDD"></AlternatingItemStyle>

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Routing Number" DataField="CUID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="True">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Account" DataField="Account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="True">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Check Number" DataField="Serial" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="True">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>

    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit:* I just noticed you are using a DataGrid, not a GridView. I would recommend changing it to a GridView before following my example.

Use the OnRowDataBound event for your gridview.

So, as each row is generated in your gridview, you run a check to see if the row has an amount equal to $10.

```
Protected Sub ERNDataGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles ERNDataGrid.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "$10" Then
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
    End If
End Sub
```

Change the code to fit your specifications and data types.

Comment: I bit the bullet and changed to GridView. I believe part of me was being stubborn and part of me was "scared" since I am so new at this. I did have to add a RowIndex check.

`code
Private Sub ERNDataGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles ERNDataGrid.RowDataBound If e.Row.RowIndex > -1 Then If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "$500.00" Then e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow End If End If End Sub `

Nevertheless, I prevailed and I was able to get my desired result. Thank you, @Wenadin.

Answer (score 1):

A DataGrid has the ItemDataBound event that you can use.

```
protected void ERNDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a datarowview 
        DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //check the column value and color the row
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(row["amount"]) == 10)
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub ERNDataGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then

        'cast the dataitem back to a datarowview 
        Dim row As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem,DataRowView)

        'check the column value and color the row
        If (Convert.ToDecimal(row("amount")) = 10) Then
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If          

    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before you answered, I bit the bullet and changed my DataGrid to a GridView and went with the first response. After a bit of tweaking, changing properties to their new names, I was able to get my desired result from the GridView. While I am sure this output would probably work, changing everything back to see if it would work, that might take me some time. I will mark this answer as useful either way as it was what I was originally looking for.

Comment: No problem. But I guarantee it works. I test everything before posting.